# How to call java method from onclick in html code wriiten inside java program?

Tags: java, html, jsp, methods, onclick

I have tried following java code snippet ....but it doesn't work.Also i want func() to be activated only after href url is executed. Kindly help me with it.Thanks :)

```
    stringBuilder.append("<a  href=\"https://google.com\" onclick=\"myfunc(){ <%= func() %> }\" >");
    stringBuilder.append("Click here</a>");

    public static void func() {
           System.out.println("Print something");}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I get your question right. But you may want to take a look at a similar question posted here. I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.

[Calling java class from javascript written in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788889/calling-java-class-from-javascript-written-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Html is rendred on the browser (client side) then you can't call java code from it ! Instead, you can call Javascript function that invoque a backend through http or ajax

Comment: Can u please elaborate it? I have used myfunc(), js func to invoke func(), java method.

Comment: This is examples how to use onclick events https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp You need in the script part to write the function that call ajax or http in order to call a java servlet/ http endpoint